# ICustomFormatter return null with string.Format

Tags: c#

I have a custom formatter that returns null if the `arg` is null. However, `string.Format(MyCustomFormatProvider, {0:some-custom}, null)` returns an empty string. Is there any way to get around this?

I understand the documentation for `string.Format` states:

> If the value of the argument is null, the format item is replaced with
>   String.Empty.

I was hoping to `ICustomFormatter` implementation would override this by default.

```
                   ///code before ....
                     case "some-custom":
                        if (arg == null)
                        {
                            return null; //RETURN NULL DAMMIT
                        }
                        else if (arg is double)
                        {
                            var d = (double)arg;
                            return Math.Round(d, _numberFormatter.NumberDecimalDigits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString(CustomNumericFormat, this);
                        }
                        else if (arg is decimal)
                        {
                            var d = (decimal)arg;
                            return Math.Round(d, _numberFormatter.NumberDecimalDigits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString(CustomNumericFormat, this);
                        }
                 //code after....
```

Comment: `String.Format` never returns `null`, so you need to use a different way. What you want to display in that case?

Comment: Why do you want `string.Format()` to return null?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Amy I am looping through a large dataset to prep for the presentation layer - and the "formatted" strings get dumped into a generic object dictionary. Unfortunately the code at the presentation layer wants it to be null if nothing is there. I am dealing with nullable doubles and decimals among other things. Obviously this is not an ideal design... I painfully realize this everyday.

Comment: Follow it up with an `if(str.Length == 0) { str = null; }` or some equivalent.

Comment: @Amy, ya thats what I am thinking as well.... Was hoping ICustomFormatter could do that out of the box but I guess I get it... If you want to put that into an answer, I am good with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your custom formatter returns a string to be inserted where the pattern holder (`{0:some-custom}`) is.  It isn't returning the final result.  Inserting null into a string is identical to that string.

`String.Format()` is defined by the documentation such that it *always* returns a `string`.  Even if you *could* change that, it would be a violation of its contract.  That is sub-optimal.

Instead, follow the `String.Format(...)` call up with an if(str.Length == 0) { str = null; } or some equivalent to prevent empty strings from getting to the UI.